# Centering an image(vertically and horizontally) on another background image?

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I am trying to **center an image**(door)(within a div) both ***vertically*** and **horizontally** on another div which has a background image.

Have been stuck on this for a while..

This is what i tried so far:

**CSS**:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    width:100%;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Zd7A3rZ.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#background{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

#doorDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top :50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid 4px;
}
```

**Conditions:**

- I need the door image smaller,like around 25% of the height of the background image.
- The whole thing should be **responsive**
- Please **don't** make any change to the elements.

**Here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37zHh/)**

Comment: Like this? [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/37zHh/1/) Only just read don't change the element lol.

Comment: @Ruddy Close,The inner image has to be responsive too...

Comment: It's `25%` of the height and centers. What do you mean?

Comment: well,the height of the door is about right initially,What i meant was.. try shrinking the width of the page down to mobile size without any change to the height ,the door width and height remains the same right? (even thought the background is responsive)

Comment: Erm, I think so? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/37zHh/6/) Like this?

Comment: @Ruddy Yup,perfect.
Do post your answer..I will accept it :)

Comment: All done, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need ie9+ I suggest you use the transform solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/37zHh/4/

```
#doorDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top :50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid 4px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    width: 25%;
}
```

and for the door scaling:

```
#doorDiv img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

But as I said above, this only works ie9+ http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Yep,ie9+ is fine..
So if i have to shorten the image.. i would have to replace the door image with a smaller image?

Comment: No, just change the width of the #doorDiv to something smaller (right now it's 25%)

Comment: Is it? Lol it pops out if you change the height. But fair enough lol

Comment: I don't know Ruddy, personally I would have chosen your solution, but maybe mine suits him better in his case.

Answer (score 1):

Right o! So I have provided the code that has changed. You can clearly see whats happening here. Just centering the `img` using `absolute` and `margin: auto` then setting a `max-width` and `max-height` and that about does it.

### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="door" src="http://i.imgur.com/iXiL1CS.jpg" />
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    width:100%;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Zd7A3rZ.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#door {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    left:0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width:10%;
    max-height:25%;
    width: auto0;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 4px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/37zHh/6/)